# How to Select all objects that have the subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: python, scripting, selection-tools, select

I saw this example of how to select objects by name with a script, I would like to know if anyone knows how to modify it to be able to select all the objects with the subdivision surface modifier.

Thank you very much

```
# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    # Check for given object names
    if o.name in ("Cube.026","Cube.027","Cube.028"):
        o.select_set(True)
```

Answer (score 2):

First approximation

Gives you a list of objects matching the criteria in the current scene

```
import bpy

mlist = [xbbb for xbbb in bpy.data.objects if [xxx for xxx in xbbb.modifiers  if 'SUBSURF' == xxx.type and xbbb.name in bpy.context.scene.objects]]

for bbb in mlist:
    bbb.select_set(True)
    print(bbb.name)
```

mlist = [xbbb for xbbb in bpy.data.objects if [xxx for xxx in xbbb.modifiers  if 'SUBSURF' == xxx.type and xbbb.name in bpy.context.scene.objects]]

Please make suitable adjustments.  You may need to horizontal scroll to see all above.

---

More verbose and across all scenes

[xbbb for xbbb in bpy.data.objects if len([xxx for xxx in xbbb.modifiers  if 'SUBSURF' == xxx.type])]

Please see Python comprehension list